# Create App Package Bundle Creation Failed. Access is denied

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to run Create App Packages in Visual Studio 2013 for my Windows 8.1 Store app. After validating my license and selecting the app name it fails with the following:

1. Bundle creation failed.
2. 0x80070005 - Access is denied.

The file its referring in the Error List is MakeAppx.

Sounds like a simple access restriction but I have no idea where the restriction is and I'm running as administrator anyway.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/hh446767.aspx#create_package_using_mapfile

Pay atention to:
To create a package using a directory structure
To create a package using a mapping file

If you are specifying a struct. You need uses args -d.
If not, uses -f.